# Remove 1px border from images

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick

I have tried looking for a way to process images from the command line. I have stumbled upon imagemagick but am struggling to figure out how to do it. I am using Mac OS X and just need to remove 1px from around the entire image - do I even need imagemagick or am I missing something easier?

The images are all different sizes. I would like to iterate over all of the images in a folder and remove the 1px from around them image. Any ideas? For example - a 100px by 100px image would becom 98px by 98px by the time i remove the border from both sides.

I would supply code - but I unfortunately have not been able to google the correct syntax for the solution I am working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shave

I think this imagemagick option should do it nicely.  As for whether you need imagemagick, *shrug*, it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep original images you can use:

```
convert input.jpg -shave 1x1 output.jpg
```

otherwise this command will remove 1px border from the original image:

```
mogrify -shave 1x1 input.jpg
```